# Intellij XSLT with PHP function on Windows

Tags: php, xml, xslt, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have intellij installed on windows and PHP installed on the same machine.
I have an XSLT file with a PHP function in it, when running it via PHP and using registerPHPFunctions it's fine but I want to use Intellij to debug it but I keep getting an error:
[FATAL]: file:/M:/default.xslt: line 234: The URI http://php.net/xsl does not identify an external Java class

What do I need to configure?

Comment: I guess your IDE is mainly a Java IDE and uses Java XSLT processors like Xalan or Saxon while PHP uses libxslt, a C implementation. Any use of extension functions is usually processor specific and dependent so I would not expect a Java based XSLT implementation to support a PHP specific extension function.

Comment: So is there anyway to change Intellijs XSLT processor (it does use SAXON)?